# How to get the name of a closed channel for ticket system so it can be logged?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to think of a way to get the channel name that the `c!close` command will be ran in so the channel can be logged in the logs channel when it gets deleted or closed.

This might be an easy task to do, but I can't think of the solution to this off the top of my head, and was unable to find anything on google to help.

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  name: "close",
  aliases: ["delete"],
  description: "Closes an open ticket",
  usage: "close",
  run: async (client, message, args) => {
    if (!message.member.permissions.has("MANAGE_CHANNELS")) {
      return message.reply("You do not have perms to use this command. - `[MANAGE_CHANNELS]`")
    }
        
    if (message.channel.name.includes("ticket-")) {
      message.reply("Closing ticket, please wait...").then(msg => {
        setTimeout(() => msg.channel.delete(), 3000)
      }).catch();
    } else {
      return message.reply("This is not a ticket channel, please run this command inside of an open ticket channel.");
    }
    
    const logchannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "action-log");
      if (logchannel) {
        const ticketLogs = new MessageEmbed()
          .setTitle("Ticket Closed")
          .addField("Name", `<:CL_Reply:909436090413363252> \`CHANNEL NAME\``) //I want to be able to get the name of the channel that is being deleted so it can be logged in my logs channel.
          .addField("Closed by", `<:CL_Reply:909436090413363252> \`${message.author.tag}\``)
          .addField("Closed", `<:CL_Reply:909436090413363252> <t:${Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)}:R>`)
          .setFooter("Crimson - Ticket Logger", client.user.displayAvatarURL())
          .setColor("RED")
          .setTimestamp();
        logchannel.send({ embeds: [ticketLogs] });
       }
  }
};
```

this command is for my ticket system for my bot, so it will be helpful to get info off of a closed channel whenever this command is executed inside of the channel.

Comment: Try using `message.channel.name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is have a temporary variable outside of the ticket check code which can be set as the channel name.

```
    if (!message.member.permissions.has("MANAGE_CHANNELS")) {
      ...
    }
    let deletedTicketName;
    if (message.channel.name.includes("ticket-")) {
      message.reply("Closing ticket, please wait...").then(msg => {
        deletedTicketName = message.channel.name;
        setTimeout(() => msg.channel.delete(), 3000)
      }).catch();
    } else {
      ...
    }
```

and then reference that in the logging part.

*IF you just assign a the variable as the channel, it may not exist as you do .delete(), however I am not 100% sure of that.*

There may be another way of doing it but this works and you get any of the channel information.